# How to generate XML from template? (NoMethodError in Leads#create) (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, csv, templates

I want to generate an `XML` file from my template `sendfile.xml.erb` and send it via email on Lead create method.

It works fine when I generate a CSV in lead.rb without using a template.

But how do I make Rails render the `XML` template instead, in `lead.rb`?

**lead.rb:**

```
class Lead < ApplicationRecord

    def self.generate_xml
    CSV.generate do |xml|
        xml << LeadsController.render('leads/sendfile')
    end
  end
```

---

**leads_controller.rb:**

```
    class LeadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lead, only: [:show, :edit, :sendfile, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :new, :create]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def sendfile
    @lead = Lead.find_by_id(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.xml #{ send_data @lead.generate_xml, filename: "Leads (#{Date.today.strftime("%A %b %d")}).xml"  }

      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
      response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=hi.xml"   
    end
  end

  # GET /leads/new
  def new
    @lead = Lead.new
  end

  def create
    @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
    #csv = Lead.generate_csv

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lead.save
        xml = Lead.generate_xml
        #message = "You got a new lead!"
        #TwilioTextMessenger.new(message).call

        LeadMailer.daily(@lead,@lead.user,@lead.vehicle,xml).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to @lead, notice: 'Lead was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lead }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @lead.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_lead
      @lead = Lead.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def lead_params
      params.require(:lead).permit(:user_id, :messengeruser_id, :vehicle_id, :phone, :email, :vehicle, :first_name, :last_name, :'first name', :'last name', :gender, :source, :locale, :profile_pic_url, :'profile pic url', :timezone, :messenger_user_id, :chatfuel_user_id, :'messenger user id', :'chatfuel user id', :ref, :country, :city, :state, :zip, :address, :latitude, :longitude, :map_url, :last_visited_block_name, :last_visited_block_id, :last_clicked_button_name, :last_user_freeform_input, :'last visited block name', :'last visited block id', :'last clicked button name', :'last user freeform input')
    end
end
```

[@lead is being saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkTxZ.png)

[I can open http://localhost:3000/leads/sendfile/36.xml with no problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfG6I.png)

**routes.rb**

```
  get '/leads/sendfile/:id', to: 'leads#sendfile'
```

**sendfile.xml.erb**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?ADF VERSION="1.0"?>
<adf>
    <prospect>
        <id sequence="Craigslist" source="Craigslist_NADASEO"></id>
        <requestdate><%= Date.today.strftime("%A %b %d, %Y") %></requestdate>
        <vehicle interest="buy" status="<%= @lead.vehicle.vehicle_type %>">
            <vin><%= @lead.vehicle.vin %></vin>
            <year><%= @lead.vehicle.year %></year>
            <make><%= @lead.vehicle.make %></make>
```

The XLM file is a bit longer...

[No MethodError in Leads#create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snxsV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using within rails app 
Use render_to_string helper method store it in a xml file. 
If you are using poro class then use net/http request to download the file from rails application.